# Modifying code for 61-key to 49-key keybed matrix

Tags: arduino, schematics, teensy, matrix

I'm currently working on a DIY music keyboard project and I have a newbie question as I've gotten stuck in the process and my electronics knowledge doesn't extend past some basic Arduino blink examples.

I'm trying to send signals from my keybed (Fatar 49TP/9S) to my microcontroller (Teensy 4.1) and use the Teensy to convert those signals to MIDI data. Someone has made some [example code for the implementation on a 61-key keybed](https://gist.github.com/JelaniThompson/4efd966ddde4f9c01cbdf41c28d8fabf), but I have a question regarding the T#s in the code.

Many matrix scanning implementations I've seen are highly picky about how the rows/columns of the pins are placed. As I'm using a Teensy 4.1 and this code was built for an Arduino Mega (which has all of the pins easily available facing up), some of the #define T#s at the beginning are a bit more annoying to access on my Teensy (pins 42+ require soldering).

Does anyone here know how I should go about modifying the code so that it retains its functionality whilst not using any pin number above 41? Can I literally just assign them to any pin as I please whilst not losing functionality?

There's a thread [here](https://modwiggler.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=3914037#p3914037) detailing the process with some relevant information towards the bottom.

49 Key Schematic:

[image]

61 Key Schematic:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wasn't this already asked? Looks mighty familiar?

Comment: @periblepsis yes ... definitely asked before

Comment: @JelaniThompson what have you tried? ... how did your attempt fail? ... what error did you get?

Comment: Are the keyboard matrixes identical otherwise? If yes, the code scanning for 61 keys just would not care less if there is only 49 keys connected.

Comment: Hey @Justme Thanks. Yeah, I asked a similar question before, but left out some info. My issue is that I'm not quite sure if I can modify the T#s towards the top of the code. Basically, the Arduino Mega has all its pin facing up, but in the code, some of the pin numbers that are easily accessible on the Mega aren't easily accessible on the Teensy 4.1. I was wondering if I could just change the pin numbers to start from 0 and not go past 41 and if it would break anything. I know matrix scanning stuff is highly reliant on pin position. I tried it before, but may have been wiring wrong.

Comment: Also wanted to tag @jsotola as well.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the code? Did it work or not? What does the code do with the pins, if you suspect it does not work?

Comment: @JelaniT It appears you are already getting informed help [over here](https://modwiggler.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=221510). I believe there is a difference in the connector scanning arrangement between 49 and 61 keys, as they both start at the same low C note but the scanning *may* be different looking at your schematics. If so, may not be able to use the exact same software for both. Can you tell me the note assignments for each key in these two schematics?